# Cómo conectar mi aplicación multiusuario en Java a BD remoto?

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenas tardes:

Estoy queriendo realizar un proyecto de aprendizaje, en el mismo, quiero crear una aplicación en Java y quiero que el mismo se conecte a una BD que está en otra máquina, es decir, de forma remota. 
El objetivo es para poder aplicarlo luego en un proyecto más grande...

Desde ya, muchas gracias por la ayuda...

Comment: ¿Si es un proyecto de aprendizaje, la idea es que aprendes de hacerlo, no como pedir que alguien lo hace, cierto? Revisa [el centro de ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) como hacer una buena pregunta basado en trabajo que haz hecho. Hay que tratar primero para aprender.

Comment: Hola sería bueno que aregues algún fragmento de código para saber como intentas acceder a la bd, da un clavado en google buscando JNDI, JDBC, ahí verás como armar una cadena de conexión a BD local o remota.

Comment: Debes establecer tu el servidor al cual te vas a conectar:                         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String servidor = "jdbc:mysql://190.10.10.6:3306/baseDeDatos";
            String usu= vUsuario;
            String pass= vClave;
            conexion= DriverManager.getConnection(servidor,usu,pass);

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a todos por su aporte y respuesta a mi pregunta... en verdad, los tres comentarios me son bien útiles. Gracias Carlos por tu respuesta, la cual, ha respondido de forma concreta a mi pregunta o duda...